# .NET Performance Issues - visual studio hosting process

Tags: .net, wpf, nhibernate, visual-studio-2010

I have a .NET 4.0 Client Profile, WPF + NHibernate 3 Line of Business style application, which I have almost completely developed. The backend database is a Microsoft Access file accessed via the NHibernate contrib JetDriver.

When running the application via the debugger in Visual Studio 2010, the application performance is very acceptable. If however I run either the Debug or Release .exe file or from a ClickOnce deployment, the performance of the whole application is extremely sluggish.

After searching on google, I found that disabling the 'visual studio hosting process' option would make my debugging experience similar to running the .exe file directly, which it did.

What I would like to know is, why is it I am experiencing such a slow down with respect to the normal debugging mode? And how can I improve matters at run time.

Compile Settings are as shown:

[image]

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate performance problems can often be attributed to log4net configuration. If you are using log4net and the level is set to DEBUG NHibernate will do a lot of logging. This may also be the reason that performance is acceptable in the the VS debugger but not deployment. log4net may not have write access to a folder in the deployment environment so it's failing to open the log file. See this link: http://jagregory.com/writings/empty-nhibernate-logs-and-poor-performance/.

PS - I'm having a hard time reconciling line-of-business application with Access back end.

Comment: "PS - I'm having a hard time reconciling line-of-business application with Access back end." lol, I know! the application is more like a proof of concept.

Comment: In NHibernate 3.0 (CR1), there is now no references to log4net. I also have the configuration element 'show_sql' set to false. Do I have to explicitly disable some other internal logging